# Clean up after killing a thread

Tags: linux-kernel, multithreading, memory-leaks, pthreads

After reading this article https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/l-memory-leaks/ I'm wondering is there a way to cancel thread execution and avoid memory leaks. Since my understanding is that the join functionality is releasing the allocated space. That should be possible to do also by other commands. The thing that interest me how does join releases the memory space and other functions cant? Is there a function that gives to witch thread a memory space is assigned? Can this be given out (the mapping)? I know one should not do crazy things with that since it represents an potential safety issue. But still are there ways to achieve that?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're asking. Sure, there are lots of other ways to do it. If functions like `pthread_join` don't do exactly what you want, don't use them and manage it some other way. You can write code that is cancellable using `pthread_cancel` or, again, any other mechanism you want if that's not appropriate. What's the problem you're having with just coding exactly what you want?

Comment: @Mr. Schwartz, the problems that I have to solve are quite big. For example if I have a third party lib then I can identify its threads but I have the problem that I cannot identify allocated memory spaces in the lib, or I do not know how to do that (the lib is a binary). Coding such stuff is a rabbit hole and should be done on the OS level. Posix allows canceling but not identifying the individual threads, and not all Posix functionality works on linux. Posix is just a layer over the stl stuff in the OS.

Comment: My thoughts on that were that somewhere in Linux the system tracks what allocation on heap were made by the threads if some option is enabled since I know by default there is nothing. But I see there is no answer to a serious question.

Answer (score 1):

> For example if I have a third party lib then I can identify its threads but I have the problem that I cannot identify allocated memory spaces in the lib, or I do not know how to do that (the lib is a binary).

If the library doesn't support that, you can't. Your understanding of the issue is slightly off. It doesn't matter who allocated the memory, it matters whether the memory still needs to be allocated or not. If the library provides some way to get to the point where the memory no longer needs to be allocated, that provided way would also provide a way to free the memory. If the library doesn't provide any way to get to the point where the memory no longer needs to be allocated, some way to free it would not be helpful.

> Coding such stuff is a rabbit hole and should be done on the OS level.

Can't be done. The OS has no way to know when the code that allocated some chunk of memory still needs it and when it doesn't. Only the code that allocated the memory can possibly know that.

> Posix allows canceling but not identifying the individual threads, and not all Posix functionality works on linux. Posix is just a layer over the stl stuff in the OS.

Right, so POSIX is not the place where this goes. It requires understanding of the application and so must be done at the application layer. If you need this functionality, code it. If you need it in other people's code and they don't supply it, talk to them. Presumably, if their code is decent and appropriate, it has some way to d what you need. If not, your complaint is with the code that doesn't do what you need.

> My thoughts on that were that somewhere in Linux the system tracks what allocation on heap were made by the threads if some option is enabled since I know by default there is nothing.

That doesn't help. Which thread allocated memory tells you absolutely nothing about when it is no longer needed. Only the same code that decided it was needed can tell when it is no longer needed. So if this is needed in some code that allocates memory, that code must implement this. If the person who implemented that code did not provide this kind of facility, then that means they decided it wasn't needed. You may wish to ask them why they made that decision. Their answer may well surprise you.

> But I see there is no answer to a serious question.

The answer is to code what you need. If it's someone else's code and they didn't code it, then they didn't think you would need it. They're most likely right. But if they're wrong, then don't use their code.

Comment: Ok this gives me some confirmation on my worst fears. The problem is that the costs are mounting quite a bit (long and nasty story). I get your idea about tracking code allocations. But my idea goes only to the case I have to cancel threads. I know if some other code needs the mem allocation this needs to be resolved. The problem is if I say now my team needs this list of functionality this will create cost and time issues (many suppliers), that is why I was asking that question in first place since there are many people creating all sorts of solutions. My next go to is forking things out.

Comment: @MarkoBencik Why not just wrap the library in its own process? Or check with the library author/vendor to see what forms of cancellation is supports? But you can't just magically make code cleanly cancelable if it wasn't designed to be cleanly cancelable.

Comment: @Mr. Schwartz, that was the scenario I wanted to avoid. But I see I have to change the concept of the app into multi process and then solve the cancellation as a defined state machine. With known behavior. Thnx for the responses.